# HTML link to CSS style sheet not working

Tags: html, css, href

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> A Level Computing </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="College Work/Computing/homework2part3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class='row headingrow'>
    <div class='grid-d-1'> <h1> AS Theory</h1></div>
    <div class='grid-d-1'> <h1> AS Programming</h1></div>
    <div class='grid-d-1'><img src='pictures/menu_logo.png'
                                alt='Computing'/></div>
    <div class='grid-d-1'> <h1> A2 Theory</h1></div>
    <div class='grid-d-1'> <h1> A2 Programming</h1></div>
 </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS code is:

```
* { 
    box-sizing: border-box
}

[class*="grid-"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

@ media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For Desktop*/
    .grid-d-1{width: 20%}
    .grid-d-1{width: 25%}
    .grid-d-1{width: 100%}
} 

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

My HTML webpage isn't being altered like it should be and i think its down to my linking between the html and css. Also my image isnt coming up. It may be down to my file directory. The code is not completely finished yet just so you know.

I think it has something to do with my file directory as my images ( i have added another) arent coming up.

Comment: Remove empty spaces from folder name, they (spaces) get url encoded. Also, pay attention to lowercase and uppercase letters - linux is case sensitive (if you host site on linux based system).

Comment: re-check your href location is ok or not

Comment: They are in the same folder, with other html documents

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you have three values for the same class

```
.grid-d-1{width: 20%}
.grid-d-1{width: 25%}
.grid-d-1{width: 100%}
```